# Check state before render for react native

Tags: react-native, react-router

I need to get the user's name the first time the app is run.  Then after I want to skip the first screen and go directly to the second screen.

I'm using `AsyncStorage.getItem("first")` in the first screen to check if this is the first boot.  If not, `navigate('SecondScreen')`.

The problem is that the first screen flash for half a second before going to the second screen.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Render a loader and check AsyncStorage until the data is loaded, then navitage or render your component conditionally like so:

```js
constructor(){
   super()
   this.state = {
      hasName: null, loaded: false,
   }
}

componentDidMount(){
   this.fetchName()
}

fetchName(){
   AsyncStorage.getItem('first')
   .then((e, s)=>{
         this.setState({hasName: s ? true : false, loaded: true})
   });
}

loading(){
    return(<View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>)
}

renderLoaded(){
   if (this.state.hasName){
      return(...)
   }  else {
      navigate('secondScreen')
      return(...)
   }
}

render(){
   if (this.state.loaded){
        return this.renderLoaded()
   }
  return this.loading()
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Basicaly, you want to do something similar...

Render "loading" screen while loading data. When done, rerender with main application.

```js
class Application extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ready: false,
    user: null,
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
    this.setState({
      user,
      ready: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.ready === false) {
      // render "booting" screen while reading data from storate or remote server
      return <Boot />;
    }

    if (this.state.user === null) {
      // render Login screen
      return <Login />
    }

    // Render main navigation stack for app
    return <NavigatorStack user={this.state.user} />
  }
}
```